# How can I count the number of integer occurences from a txt file from certain columns in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, readfile

Basically to explain I have a txt document that needs to be read to file http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1515402294116.txt

How would I be able to do a number count for specifically the 3rd column? For example, the first 10 numbers in the 3rd column on the txt document starting from the top are...

```
1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1 ,1, 3, 1, 2
```

If I were to do a number count for the value of 3 it would be:

```
"The number 3 occurs: 3 times"
```

But I have a really big sample, and I want to only include these values for the `3rd column`, would anyone be able to help me I've been stuck on this problem for a while. I'm thinking you would have to set each columns in arrays and work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text file looks like tab delimited, you could read each line using [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and extract third column each time. Number count can be easily done using streams.

```
    File file = new File(PATH_TO_TXT);
    ArrayList<Integer> storage = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] arr = line.split("\t");
            storage.add(Integer.valueOf(arr[2].trim()));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Map<Integer, Long> occurrences = storage.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Hello Michael thanks for the answer, I'm not familiar with counting by streams, how would you count how many 4's are in the 3rd column for instance?

Comment: @jonlajoey The stream maps the integer to the count for that specific integer. You would use `occurrences.get(4);` to return the count.

Comment: The stream in the code counts occurrences of every number, so at the end you could just use `occurrences .get(4)` or change stream to: `storage.stream().filter(e -> e == 4).count()`.

Comment: Sorry I've tried at the end to change occurences.get(4), I might not be putting it in the right place, sorry I'm a noob at this. https://ideone.com/eIX3nn Where in it would you place it?

Comment: Why do you use online IDE instead of local one? Your code isn't working on the website because you are not allowed to change class name and make it public, leave the class name as `Ideone`, try this: https://ideone.com/T6AZtx , but it won't work beacuse you need a file. You should try this code using local IDE.

Comment: I'm using a local one, I'm using it on netbeans, I just thought the online one would be easier to present to you but thank you I'll give it a go and see if it works

Comment: Thank you very much Michael Dz it's working, I really made that a lot harder than it needed to be, you get the tick!

Answer (score 0):

if every value is separated by a ',' you could use this code:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
int counter = 0;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testfile.txt"));
    String line;
    // the column you want to get:
    int column = 3;
    // the value you want to search
    String value = "3";

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int first = 0;
        int last = line.indexOf(",");
        //get index of the column
        for (int i = 0; i < column - 1; i++) {
            first = last;
            last = line.indexOf(",", last + 1);
        }
        // get the value of the column
        String column3value = line.substring(first + 1, last);
        // counter +1 for every value
        if (column3value.equals(value)) {
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```